# Is there any real advantage to use zend ce server over just referencing (include) the zend framework library?

Tags: php, zend-framework, installation

I'm new to PHP frameworks, and currently I'm trying Zend Framework (ZF). I'm old fashioned when it comes to installing software, I like to install apache/mysql/php all separetely since I find easier and it gives me more control of it.

It seems that the "encouraged" way to develop with Zend Framework is using the Zend (CE) Server. I personally don't like this idea of a app install everything else (PHP/Apache and so on).

**From what I've seen if I include Zend Framework Library in php.ini path I'm ready to go. So is there any real advantage to use the Full Zend (CE) Server??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Zend Server, especially if you're fine with setting up your own environment. On the other hand Zend Server is optimized for running Zend Framework based applications. It becomes especially meaningful when you start using Zend Studio too. There is just a smaller probability of there being any kind of issues in your AMP stack.

Apart from that, Zend Server really is a great stack. Much more advanced than all the *AMPs out there. You can for example activate and deactivate PHP extensions through a nice web GUI just by clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already developing with apache/php/mysql stack on your machine, I see no advantage to install Zend Server. As far as I can tell, Zend framework is just plain PHP, there is nothing special in the code that makes use of any Zend Server functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I got my info form [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Server) :  there is simple comparison
 between the both

the CE version misses these spec :

- Page caching
- Application monitoring  ,Does runtime monitoring of individual PHP requests several different conditions

  - Function Error Database Error Slow
  - Function Execution Slow Query
  - Execution Slow Request Execution
  - High Memory Usage Inconsistent
  - Output Size Uncaught Java Exception
  - Custom Event Fatal PHP Error
  - PHP Error
- Application problem diagnostics Zend Download Server (Linux only) - Allows for large content, such as videos, to be downloaded without tying up an Apache process
- Software updates and hot fixes

or you might find this page is helpful : http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/editions

but from my point of view : **you can customize your apache/mysql/php to be identical to the CE version**

Comment: I am considering using Zend Server CE, and I was wondering about your comment about being able to configure to be identical to CE version. Doesn't the CE version contain the Zend Optimizer+? Wouldn't that be a benefit in performance over the normal apache/mysql/php setup?

Comment: I guess Zend Optimizer+ wan't released at the time of answering this question

Comment: I still don't know a lot about the Zend products so I wanted to make sure the Optimizer+ was valuable over a default config. Thanks for replying.